# Playa tags rendering in PHP 5.4.10

Tags: channel-entries, playa, pixelandtonic

If I set my PHP instance to 5.4.10 any Playa tags are rendered as raw tags but under 5.3.20 they render correctly. Is this too new a version to play with?

Comment: Might as well be an EE's issue with parsing tags?

Without proper testing/debugging it's hard to tell.

Comment: Steven, can you let me know your version of EE and Assets?  I'll do some testing on this in the afternoon here; have some other Assets testing to do at the same time. Thank you!

Comment: EE: 2.5.2, Playa: 4.4.2

Comment: Came across issues with PHP 5.4 and Playa myself recently where previously fine tags nested in channel entries tag needed to have the entry_id parameter to work correctly.

Comment: I am also having this issue with PHP > 5.4 and EE 2.5.5, Playa latest - 4.4.3 Here is my issue with full details, posted earlier.
http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/11817/server-migration-new-lines-in-playa-tag-pair-breaking-templates Anyone know if the latest version of EE will resolve this?

Comment: Look for other extensions using the channel_entries_tagdata hook. It's likely that one of them is not respecting ee()->extensions->last_call.

Comment: @RobSanchez, could you post your recent comment as an answer? It offers good advice.

Answer (score 2):

Look for other extensions using the channel_entries_tagdata hook. It's likely that one of them is not respecting ee()->extensions->last_call.

For me, it was Better Workflow (they have since fixed the issue).