# Server Migration : New Lines in Playa Tag Pair Breaking Templates

Tags: playa, pixelandtonic, server, server-migration, parse

I have an issue where the same template - specifically Playa tag pair - works on one server, but not on another.

I just used the Plesk migration manager to move from a Media Temple DV 3.5 to DV 4. Everything about my file system and database is identical, from permissions to templates, EE version, entries etc. My mysql & php versions for each env. are listed at the bottom of this post.

The DV4, by default, runs PHP as a FastCGI application, but I have switched to run it as an Apache module, as it is on my previous server (to avoid 'no input file' .htaccess / index.php removal issues, and any others I'm not aware of).

My test template looks like so, on both servers:

```
{exp:channel:entries 
  channel="accommodation" 
  limit="1"}

  <h1>Entry Title : {title}</h1>

  <h3>Playa Tag Pair with Line Breaks</h3>

  {accommodation_locations 
    status="not Closed"}Playa Entry Title : {title}<br>{/accommodation_locations}

{/exp:channel:entries}
```

.. but the output is only correct on one of them - the older DV 3.5:

> Entry Title : Laughing Waters Guest House
>
> Playa Tag Pair with Line Breaks
>
> Playa Entry Title : Panorama Route Playa Entry Title : Kruger National
>   Park Playa Entry Title : South Africa

and the tags are not parsed on the new DV4 server:

> Entry Title : Laughing Waters Guest House
>
> Playa Tag Pair with Line Breaks
>
> {accommodation_locations status="not Closed"}Playa Entry Title :
>   Laughing Waters Guest House {/accommodation_locations}

This only happens when there are line breaks in the tag pair. Both templates are encoded as UTF-8 and changing the encoding makes no difference.

The server has Nginx running as a reverse proxy in front of Apache, but I have turned this off and it has made no difference.

Any assistance very gratefully received, as I would prefer not to have to find a new host.

*The Working DV3.5 Server Environment has PHP Version 5.2.6, MySQL 5.0.45

*The unparsed tags DV4 Server Environment has PHP Version 5.4.13, MySQL 5.5.30

Both environments have EE version 2.5.5 and the latest Playa 4.4.3, although I have also tried an older version, 4.3.3 - with no change in the results.